# transparent UIButton in iOS 5 sdk

Tags: ios5, uibutton

What is the best way to achive having test showing up as normal color but the Rect button lines being not shown effectively making it transparent.

i have tried alpha settings but no luck as it makes the whole button AND text transparent, which is not what i want i would prefer to achieve this by UIButton rather then Image.

with image i struggled to link actions / outlets among views and found it easier to connect using cntrl button and linking with views.

Any working idea would be good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a custom button:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn setTitle:@"Push me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.1 blue:0.4 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: I believe you meant for your first line of code to be :`UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];` not rounded rect type.

Comment: By doing the button paragmatically would it stil be able to connect with outlets and actions just like standard button? also which section in the code this goes in (sorry i'm bit new to ios) im guessing goes in implemntation file under viewDidLoad?

Comment: Well, creating it by code is more "standard" than using IB :) To say, yes, it will still cooperate. And put the code wherever you initialize your view(controller)

Comment: Easier option is by just setting Button Type to Custom Type.

Comment: IDK how it's going. I don't use IB.